# how to back up contacts from oneplus one to google account

Tags: backup, google-account, oneplus-one, google-contacts

how do I backup my contacts from my oneplus one to google account or make a vcf file? i have tried to sync with setting>accounts>google>contacs(sync) on my phone but it doesn't save the contacts to google account. please help.

Comment: Have you tried the contacts/people app? *Menu › Export/Import › Export to card*? That would ump all contacts into a single `.vcf` file on the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Yiou have to move your contacts from SIM card or Phone storage to the Gmail

1. Go to the contacts app and in the menu ( 3 dots in top right corner ) there is `Import/Export`.
2. Select `Import from SIM`.
3. Now mark all contacts you want to move, there is button to `Select all`
4. Click `Ok` and select to move them to `Google account`
5. Now wait till it sync your contacts into Gmail, they will be visible at [Google contacts](https://contacts.google.com/)